# File Uploader in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, swfupload

I've been following the documentation [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_file_uploader_in_your_component) to add a (improved) file upload section to an existing component.

The link in the example above to the controller/model to then process the upload is formed through the post params:

```
    post_params: 
    {
            "option" : "com_mycomponent",
            "controller" : "mycontroller",
            "task" : "mytask",
            "id" : "'.$myItemObject->id.'",
            "'.$session->getName().'" : "'.$session->getId().'",
            "format" : "raw"
    },
```

My problem is the upload isn't working using the new controller methods introduced in Joomla 2.5:

```
// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by the component
$controller = JController::getInstance('mycomponent');

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

This worked (and indeed on Joomla 2.5) does work absolutely fine on the old 1.5 method for loading a controller:

```
// Create the controller
$classname  = 'mycomponentController'.$controller;
$controller = new $classname( );

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute( JRequest::getVar('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

Whilst this latter method is Joomla 2.5 compatible, unfortunately the component I wish to integrate this with uses the newer method and I'd rather not change this so I can keep updating the component as required without having to change this every time. Also if I did change it I'm guessing I may loose the existing features.

Basically I want to know how to set up the post params so that the new controller method is called correctly!

---

**EDIT**

I have since tried using a post param configuration of:

```
post_params: 
{
    "option" : "com_mycomponent",
    "task" : "mycontroller.mytask",
    "id" : "'.$myItemObject->id.'",
    "'.$session->getName().'" : "'.$session->getId().'",
    "format" : "raw"
},
```

I an attempt to emulate a link along the lines of `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mycontroller.mytask` etc. But this still doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define below variable in index.php

```
define('_JREQUEST_NO_CLEAN', 1);
```

I was looking for the cause and I found this-
http://docs.joomla.org/Framework_Compatibility

Note- If this does not work remove `"format" : "raw"`.

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: When you say in index.php is this in the main (admin) root Joomla index.php file?

Comment: @GeorgeWilson:If you are working in admin it'll be of administrator  else of front.

Comment: Sorry its taken so long to reply to this - but I'm still having the same 500 error issue with this!

Comment: @GeorgeWilson:You are missing token than.add token also with the parameter.

Comment: OK sorry I just noticed your intial thing about removing format:raw - tried it and it worked like a charm. Didn't even need the `define('_JREQUEST_NO_CLEAN', 1);`. Not quite sure why this made such a difference verses the old version - if you could explain would be much appreciated - but thanks so much for solving it!!

Comment: @GeorgeWilson:When we add format:raw it looks for the controller like this- /administrator/components/com_component/controllers/controller.raw.php when this file is not found it throws 500 error controller not found.Hope this is clear.

Comment: It does make sense - so why did this work and why is it recommended for Joomla 1.5 - was this controller naming no longer the case?

Comment: @GeorgeWilson:I have not worked much in 1.5 so I cant say for sure what is the reason.But most certainly naming is the case.